# Adding an extra index to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of DataFrame, which is read something like this

```
data = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=None) for f in temp]
flow = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If I print the `flow` I get an output of

```
[[....
[128 rows x 14 columns]]
[128 rows x 14 columns]]
.
.
[128 rows x 14 columns]]]
```

So this means that each of the `[128 rows x 14 columns]` has one index, I have `60` as such. What I wanted to do was to read another CSV file which contains one column of data (60 rows) which looks something like this

```
[1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 ... 3 3 3]
```

I can read this by doing

```
new_data=pd.read_csv(f_new, index_col=None, header=None)
```

Now my question is can I keep everything as it is and just add the `new_data` as extra index, which should show something like this:

```
[[....
0 1 [128 rows x 14 columns]]
1 1 [128 rows x 14 columns]]
2 1 .
3 2 .
4 2 [128 rows x 14 columns]]]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try: `flow = flow.set_index([flow.index, new_data])`?

Comment: @MaxU This seems to work can I name these two indexes? and also can you post this answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
flow = flow.set_index([flow.index, new_data]).rename_axis(['idx_col1','idx_col2'])
```